# Just started Java, Is this an appropriate solution to 99 Bottles of Beer on the Wall?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, do-while

Link to the problem: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/99_Bottles_of_Beer

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of bottles of beer on the wall: ");

    int X = input.nextInt();

    do {
        if (X == 1) {
            System.out.println(X + " bottle of beer on the wall");
            System.out.println(X + " bottle of beer");
            System.out.println("Take one down, pass it around");
            System.out.println(X-- + " bottle of beer on the wall");
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            System.out.println(X + " bottles of beer on the wall");
            System.out.println(X + " bottles of beer");
            System.out.println("Take one down, pass it around");
            System.out.println(X-- + " bottles of beer on the wall");
            System.out.println();
        }
    } while (X >= 0);
}
```

}

Are there better ways of doing this? I have touched a tiny bit on recursion at school, but do not know how to implement it in Java yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well you could avoid hard-to-spot side effects... `System.out.println(X-- + " bottles of beer on the wall");`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the number of bottles, I would use a for loop instead of a do while. Since the number of bottles entered could be 1 I would use a while instead of a do/while (use a do/while if you want it to happen at least once).

Stylistically, X should be x, or better yet, numberOfBottles.

I'd also move the:

```
System.out.println();
```

Out of the if/else as it is the same for both.

And, finally, I'd also move the `X--` to a line by itself so that people don't have to think does the `X--` happen before or after the print.

Comment: Is there any specific reason as to why you suggest a for loop over a do/ while loop? Is it because of efficiency? I am not too sure what you mean by "happen at least once", could you reiterate?

Comment: In general: use a for loop when you know how many times it will iterate; use a while loop when you want it to happen 0 or more times; use a do/while when you want it to happen 1 or more times.

Comment: How would I write the for loop sysout code if I wanted the sentences to be grammatically correct?

Comment: No different really, you can write a while, do/while/for for any loop, some are jsut better for certain things than others. I'd suggest looking at the solutions here that put the final prints outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very easy implantation of a for loop. Note: I used "\n" which is how you do a new line after you print to the console, in case you are not familiar

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of bottles of beer on the wall: ");

    int numOfBottles = input.nextInt();

    for(int i = numOfBottles; i >= 1; i--){
        System.out.println(i + " bottle of beer on the wall");
        System.out.println(i + " bottle of beer");
        System.out.println("Take one down, pass it around");
        System.out.println(i-1 + " bottle of beer on the wall\n");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this do-while loop:-

```
    do {
        System.out.println(X + " bottles of beer on the wall");
        System.out.println(X + " bottles of beer");
        System.out.println("Take one down, pass it around");
        X--;
        System.out.println(X + " bottles of beer on the wall\n");
    } while (X > 0);
```